# How to select and add a featureclass through GXDialogue

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

I am new to arcobject
i have learned how to add a feature class by specifying its name in code through gxdialogue.

i want to change it so i could directly select the the featureclass instead mentioning its name in coding (i.e. want to remove hardcoding).

can you please suggest what changes i need to do in code.

below is the code:

```
  IGxDialog gxd = new GxDialogClass();
        gxd.AllowMultiSelect = false;
        gxd.ButtonCaption = "Add featureclass";
        gxd.Title = "Add FeatureClasses";
        gxd.RememberLocation = true;
        IGxObjectFilter gxObjFilter = new GxFilterPersonalGeodatabases();



        gxd.ObjectFilter = gxObjFilter;
        IEnumGxObject gxEnumObj;
        gxd.DoModalOpen(ArcMap.Application.hWnd, out gxEnumObj);
        IGxObject gxObj = gxEnumObj.Next();
        //getting the address of PGDB
        string WSAddress = gxObj.FullName;


        IMxDocument mxdoc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;

        IWorkspaceFactory wsf = new AccessWorkspaceFactoryClass();

        IWorkspace ws = wsf.OpenFromFile(WSAddress, arcMap.Application.hWnd);



        IFeatureWorkspace fws = ws as IFeatureWorkspace;
        IFeatureClass fc = fws.OpenFeatureClass("FetureClassName");

        IFeatureLayer fl = new FeatureLayerClass();
        fl.Name = "Feature";
        fl.FeatureClass = fc;

        mxdoc.AddLayer(fl);
        mxdoc.ActiveView.Refresh();
        mxdoc.UpdateContents();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this for feature classes:

```
private IGxDialog getDialog(string title, IGxObjectFilter filter)
{
    IGxDialog pGxDialog = new GxDialog();
    IGxObjectFilter pGxObjFilter = filter;
    pGxDialog.AllowMultiSelect = true;
    pGxDialog.ObjectFilter = pGxObjFilter;
    pGxDialog.Title = title;
    pGxDialog.ButtonCaption = "OK";

    return pGxDialog;
}

private void getFeatureClass(string title)
{
    IEnumGxObject pEnumGxObj = null;
    IGxDialog dialog = getDialog(title, new GxFilterFeatureClasses());

    if (dialog.DoModalOpen(0, out pEnumGxObj))
    {
        IGxObject pGxObj = pEnumGxObj.Next();

        if(pGxObj != null)
        {
            IGxDataset gxDataset = pGxObj as IGxDataset;
            IName name = gxDataset.Dataset.FullName;

            //open your feature class here or later
            IFeatureClass fc = name.Open() as IFeatureClass;
        }
    }
}
```

The biggest thing is to turn the IGxObject into an IGxDataset. You can get an idea of all the different objects a IGxObject can represent and when to use them [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00140000012n000000).