# Casting igxobject to ifeatureclass in ArcObjects C#?

Tags: arcobjects

[image: Form]

In above Image text box show the file path. I selected file from the igxdialog and file stored in igxobject. Now to how to casting from igxobject to ifeatureclass of selected file... but igxobject is in button1 and validate button can't access igxobject..

code:

```c#
       private void btnbrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ESRI.ArcGIS.CatalogUI.IGxDialog dlg = new ESRI.ArcGIS.CatalogUI.GxDialogClass();
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.IGxObjectFilter objfltr = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.GxFilterFeatureClassesClass();

        objfltr = dlg.ObjectFilter;
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.IEnumGxObject Sel = null;

        dlg.DoModalOpen(0, out Sel);
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.IGxObject obj = Sel.Next();
        txtdatapath.Text = obj.FullName;
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\ARC OBJECTS\nullerrors.txt");
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.IGxDataset dset = txtdatapath as ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.IGxDataset;
        ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.IName nam = dset.Dataset.FullName;
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass fcls = nam.Open() as ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select and add a featureclass through GXDialogue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242249/how-to-select-and-add-a-featureclass-through-gxdialogue)

Comment: I got it.. but above code igxobject in button1.I write casting in validate button  but i can't access igxobject.

Comment: Why do you even need to valid it? By setting the `IGxObjectFilter` you ensure are selecting a valid featureclass. If you need pass the `IGxObject` around the code in your form simply declare it at the form level rather than in a function so it is locally global.

Comment: Make obj global then test in the validate if (obj == null) return; to see if the validate is clicked *before* a valid GxObject is selected. You can't access obj in button2_click because its scope is btnbrowse_click, if you declare ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.IGxObject obj as class global (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368129/c-sharp-global-variables) it can be accessed by both routines. You can't cast txtdatapath as IGxDataset because it's a **textbox** not a **GxObject** and does not implement the GxDataset coclass but you can cast obj to IGxDataset.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `obj` is inaccessible due to its scope.. you have declared it in `btnbrowse_Click` which limits its scope to that procedure. You cannot cast `txtdatapath as IGxDataset` because it's a [textbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx) which does not implement [IGxDataset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/IGxDataset_Interface/0014000000vr000000/) so `dset` is `null`.

You can broaden the scope of `obj` so that it is available to both procedures but be sure that you haven't declared `obj` anywhere else; as the scope of the variable increases any other instance of `obj` being declared in a procedure is a [duplicate definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.duplicatenameexception(v=vs.110).aspx) and your compiler won't like it.

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.IGxObject obj; // obj has a module wide scope

// make sure that there are no other instances of the variable named 'obj' in your
// procedures or your compiler will refuse to build.
private void btnbrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ESRI.ArcGIS.CatalogUI.IGxDialog dlg = new ESRI.ArcGIS.CatalogUI.GxDialogClass();
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.IGxObjectFilter objfltr = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.GxFilterFeatureClassesClass();

    objfltr = dlg.ObjectFilter;
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.IEnumGxObject Sel = null;

    dlg.DoModalOpen(0, out Sel);
    obj = Sel.Next(); // object is set here
    txtdatapath.Text = obj.FullName;
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (obj == null) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select an object before trying to validate");
        return;
    }

    // use the streamwriter in a using block to ensure it's closed and released properly
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\ARC OBJECTS\nullerrors.txt"))
    {
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.IGxDataset dset = obj as ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.IGxDataset; // object is accessible here
        ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.IName nam = dset.Dataset.FullName;
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass fcls = nam.Open() as ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass;
    } // you don't need to close the sreamwriter, it should be closed and released now.
}
```

Your code would benefit from a few using statements, up the very top of your code, that way you don't need to implicitly define all your objects.. for example if you add `using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase;` defining fcls changes from:

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass fcls = nam.Open() as ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass;
```

to

```
IFeatureClass fcls = nam.Open() as IFeatureClass;
```

Which is a bit more readable and less typing.